# Need Help Creating Query Layer From Oracle For Past 365 Days

Tags: oracle-spatial, date, query-layer

I have several Query layers that work fine for generic, long term date ranges such as:

This shows all entries that have the previous YEAR in the date field.

```
AND To_char(ds.calendar_date, 'YYYY') = To_char(( Extract(year FROM add_months(sysdate, -12)) ))
```

This shows all entries of previous 12 months as well as ALL of previous year

```
AND To_char(ds.calendar_date, 'YYYY') = To_char(( Extract(year FROM add_months(sysdate,-12)) )) 
AND To_char(ds.calendar_date, 'YYYY') = To_char(( Extract(year FROM sysdate) ))
```

I need something that will show the previous 365 days.

I've tried using `AND To_char(ds.calendar_date) >= To_char(sysdate-365)` but I get nothing. I've done several iterations with (and without) the To_char operator but nothing does it. The sysdate-365 gives me records from 2004?! I feel like the answer is simple and it will be something along the lines of an ESRI / Oracle / Query layer oddity.

Comment: This is an Oracle SQL question. A [google](https://www.google.com/#q=oracle+query+last+year) returns lots of SE hits.

Comment: I would normally agree. However, since ESRI manages it's queries just a flavor to the left of vanilla SQL / Oracle Query language I figured it would fit it's own bill. But if the powers that be haven't used ESRI enough then I suppose it would look like just a Database question.

Comment: No, query layers are database entities, through and through.  There is some buffer overflow security testing (which can be disabled), but Oracle is carrying the load.